# Explanation of how a holomorphic function inside the unit ball can be extended to a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: B(0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic inside the ball, and continuous on the closed ball so that $|f(z)| = 1$ for $|z| = 1$. Prove that $f$ extends to a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$.

To solve this problem, I need to define a extension of $f(z)$, let's call it $g(z)$, that satisfies three properties:

1. It is holomorphic
2. It is defined outside the ball
3. It equals $f(z)$ on the boundary of the ball

I have four candidates for $g(z)$, and I know which conditions each candidate satisfies and does not satisfy, but I am not quite sure why:

**Try 1:**
$$g(z) = f(\frac{1}{z})$$

This is defined outside the ball. I know it does not equal $f(z)$ on the boundary of the ball, but why precisely is this the case?

**Try 2:**
$$g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$$

This is not defined outside the ball and doesn't equal $f(z)$ on the boundary, but why are these facts true?

**Try 3:**

$$g(z) = f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})$$

This is not holomorphic, but satisfies the other two conditions. However, why precisely does $g(z) = f(z)$ on the boundary in this case?

**Try 4:**

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{\overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})}}$$

This satisfies all three conditions. But why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a good way to do this is to use the [Scwarz reflection principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle). This allows you to extend a function which defined on the upper half plane $\mathcal{Im}(z)>0$ and real on the real axis to the entire complex plane by defining
$$
f(z) = \overline{f(\bar {z})}
$$
for $\mathcal{Im}(z)<0$. In order to apply this, try using an appropriate conformal mapping $h$ to map $B(0,1)$ to the upper half plane in order to get a function defined on the correct region and satisfying the correct conditions.

You could also proceed directly, defining $g(z) = 1/\overline{f(\bar z)}$ for $|z|>1$, but using the Reflection principle takes care of the hard work of proving your new function is holomorphic at $|z|=1$.